# working with Javascript object model

Tags: javascript, raphael

What i am trying to achieve is creating some objects by following a better pattern. I am using Raphael.js library for creation of graphical shapes.

Problem is at the line:

```
X: "" + this.canvas_X + this.paper["width"]/2 - self.width/4,
```

The error i am getting is :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of undefined
```

I figured out that error is at `this.paper["width"]/2`. 
I am new to using javascript and not able to understand what error i am doing

```
var Graphics={
        create_canvas: function(){
                $("#canvasdiv").append("<div id='id1' width='80px' height='50px'></div>");
        },
        canvas_X:get_LEFT_TOP("canvasdiv")[0],
        canvas_Y:get_LEFT_TOP("canvasdiv")[1],
        canvas_width:function(){return $("#canvasdiv").width()},
        canvas_height:function(){return $("#canvasdiv").height()},
        paper:{
            width:900,
            height:700,
            create: function(){
                return new Raphael(document.getElementById('canvasdiv'),this.width,this.height);
            }
        },
        vswitch:{
            color:"Black",
            text:"vSwitch",
            width:"150",
            height:"150",
            X: "" + this.canvas_X + this.paper["width"]/2 - self.width/4,
            Y: Graphics.canvas_Y,
            delay:"2000",
            create: function(paper){
                setTimeout(function(){
                        paper.rect(X,Y,width,height).attr({fill : "black"})
                        },delay);
            }
        },
}
```

This is the way the call is being made:

```
 Graphics.create_canvas();
    p=Graphics.paper.create();
    Graphics.vswitch.create(p);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you enter your code, try: `Graphics.paper` it shouldn't throw any errors. However `this.paper["width"]` doesn't have paper as a property. In that case `this` refers to the object being created which will be known as `vswitch`.

Check out this code:

```
var obj = { x: 0, y: this.x }
```

The browser doesn't complain, however y is undefined. Based on the rules of creating objects, when it goes to create y, it doesn't know x exists on `this` or `obj`.

The following works:

```
var obj = { x: 0 }
obj.y = obj.x
```

Tips: You're using `this` at the wrong time, i'd suggest exploring what `this` means. Ill give you the rundown.

Open your console and enter:

```
this
// Window -> blah blah

var f = function() {
    console.log(this);
}
f()
// Window -> blah blah

var me = {}
me.f = f
me.f()
// Object { f: f() }
```

In short, `this` refers to the owner of a function. Otherwise it refers to the `Window`, and if you're creating an object `this` isn't bound until the object is finished (i.e. at the end of the brackets).